# Cleaning mixed decimal separators after Excel import (gsub maybe?)

Tags: r

I needed to read several Excel files and used the gdata package. Unfortunately the files were formated lazily, some with "," decimal/thousand separators some with "." and some with none.

To get you an idea, the numbers can look like this:

```
#Five Times 1000.1 and four times 1000.0
x <- c("1,000.1","1.000.1","1000.1","1000,1","1.000,1","1000","1,000","1.000","1000.0")
x
```

Is there a general way to convert these into 1000.1 and 1000.0 respectively? I thought about using gsub() and a regexp.

A first gsub() to replace the "," with "." and for a second gsub() a regexp might be done in a way that all "." which have three numbers to the right of it are deleted while the other "." are kept.

However I'm not familiar with regexp and don't know how to do that. Can anybody help?
Is there a simpler way to clean excel sheets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gsub` for example:

```
 as.numeric(gsub('([0-9])[,|.]?([0-9]{3})[,|.]?','\\1\\2.',x))
[1] 1000.1 1000.1 1000.1 1000.1 1000.1 1000.0 1000.0 1000.0 1000.0
```

For this specific case you can even simplify the regular expression to:

```
 as.numeric(gsub('^(1)[,|.]?(0{3})[,|.]?','\\1\\2.',x))
```

And here I decorticate the last regular expression:

```
 ^         | 1  | [,|.]?          |   0{3}    |    [,|.]?          |   (0|1)?
 beginwith | 1  | comma or point  |  3 zeros  |   comma or point   | 0 or 1 or nothing
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to work superb, thank you so much!
Do you know where I could read up on regular expressions?

Comment: @Ruben personnaly I use [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this!
Currently I am still having problems with smaller and larger numbers though:

x <- c("-", "0", "0,1", "0.2", "10" ,"10.1", "10,2", "200", "200.1", "200,2", "3000", "3000,1", "3.000,2", "3000.3", "3,000.4", "3.000.5", "40000", "40000,1", "40.000,2", "40000.3", "40,000.4", "40.000.5","6.000.000","6,000,000.1", "6.000.000,2", "6000000,3") 

as.numeric(gsub('([0-9])[,|.]?([0-9]{3})[,|.]?','\\1\\2.',x))

Comment: @Ruben This is really different from your first question. You should try by yourself and ask a new question if you can't get it. For example you can do this `as.numeric(gsub('([0-9])[,|.]?([0-9]{1,6})[,|.]?','\\1\\2.',x))` but I think you should do it in 2 steps with 2 regular expressions.

Comment: For anyone interested I now used this code:

x <- gsub("[,]",".",x)
as.numeric(gsub('([.])([0-9][0-9][0-9])','\\2',x))

which seems to work fine!
Thanks@agstudy for the help!